# Does a TensorFlow deconvolution op exist?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I need to use a deconvolution layer for image generation from a NN. Does a TensorFlow implementation exist?

Answer (score 2):

There's deconvolution in a sense of Matt Zeiler's "Deconvolutional Networks" [paper](http://www.matthewzeiler.com/pubs/cvpr2010/cvpr2010.pdf)
called `conv2d_transpose`

Found it by [searching](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=deconvolution) tensorflow github for "deconvolution"

Comment: `This operation is sometimes called "deconvolution" after (Deconvolutional Networks), but is actually the transpose (gradient) of 'conv2d' rather than an actual deconvolution.`

From the comments in the function. 

I had already found it earlier, but supposedly, this is not an actual deconvolution.

Answer (score 0):

This comment from tensorflow issues may be useful https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2169#issuecomment-216607417.

> For deconv, you can use "conv2d_backprop_input" with stride to achieve
>   similar effect. It is the gradient of the conv with stride.